# MASM - Different Variable Names Produce Crash

Tags: masm

As an assembly beginner, this error I'm getting boggles my mind. I'm working on a homework assignment (not asking for solutions), and I'm trying to store the size of a string in a variable.

So I declare a string, 'message'...

```
; init message as a string with a line break
message BYTE    "You already know what the next", 0dh, 0ah
        BYTE    "variable will be, don't you?", 0
```

...and afterwards, I use...

```
len     EQU     $-message     ; get the size of 'message'
```

...to get the size of message. However, when I tried renaming 'len' to 'length'...

```
length      EQU     $-message
```

Visual Studio (2015 Enterprise) spits out an error saying...

```
"initializer magnitude too large for specified size"
```

so........ why is this happening?

Just wondering why I can't name the variable 'length'.

Comment: `length` is a reserved word in masm.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`LENGTH` is actually [an operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zs66132.aspx).

Visual Studio 2013 produces just a syntax error for such usage, though.